# How to return content type image/jpg and inner html that byte[] in the client

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, image

I'm pulling a simple jpg from the file system like so ...

```
            var objz = "C:\\projects\\Desert.jpg";
            byte[] imageSampleData = ReadImageToBytes(objz);
            return imageSampleData;
```

(read img to btyes implementation is below)

```
byte[] ReadImageToBytes(string sPath)
        {
            byte[] data = null;
            FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(sPath);
            long numBytes = fInfo.Length;
            FileStream fStream = new FileStream(sPath, FileMode.Open,
                                                    FileAccess.Read);
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fStream);

            data = br.ReadBytes((int)numBytes);
            return data;
        }
```

Then I'm trying to return this from an ASPNET MVC ActionResult like so ...

```
return File(byteArrayFromMethodAbove, "image/jpg");
```

Then on the client I'm trying to set the src of an image like so ...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        loadImage();
    });

    function loadImage() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost:49415/Home/About",
            data: {},
            dataType: "jpg",
            success: function (datasrc) {
                $('#fk').attr('src', datasrc);
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
```

But so far the image doesn't appear to agree with what I'm doing client side (or the encoding is wrong altogether). Currently watching firebug I do see some crazy data as the src but it doesn't appear to be correct.

I've found a [ton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880515/display-image-from-database-in-asp-mvc) of [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045491/how-can-i-use-ajax-to-set-image-src-to-dynamic-image-png-data)/answers on the site but none of which seem to actually work

Any help would be much much appreciated (using MVC 2 and jQuery 1.4.1)

Comment: It looks like you're trying to point the path of the image to the bytes of the image.  The path (src) should be a URL.  Can't you just do: $('#fk').attr('src', 'http://localhost:49415/Home/About');  For some reason, SO is inserting an extra semicolon in this comment, so ignore that.

Comment: Sorry I failed to mention that I'm using Ajax here because I will return more than just the image (I'll be returning a partial view with more than just the image once I figure this out) if I go down that road what will I need to make the Ajax side happen?

Comment: If you're returning a partial view, that will be text/html content.  That means the parameter in the success function will be the html text.  You can then do something like: $('#container').html(datasrc); in your success function.  Alternatively, you can use: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Correct - in the partial how do I set src if I have type image or byte[] on my model object? That would make this much easier now that I think of it :)

Comment: Actually to help make the iPhone app vNext I think the ability to return JSON with the binary as one item and other info would be a plus - so ... Back to my first question

Comment: Actually if my JSON contains a link to the URL as u mentioned this may solve my issue - ill try this and update the post

Comment: The content type for jpeg is *image/jpeg*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use of jquery is way overkill here.  Just set src=url and let the browser do the downloading.

Comment: thanks for the simple and correct answer - seems I was doing a little over-engineering on this issue :)

Comment: Actually it is NOT overkill in all situations. My app displays a progress indicator in an img. The app then attempts to retrieve the jpg. If the jpg fails, I set the img to a default image instead. The only way you can tell if downloading a jpg fails is using the $.ajax method and checking the file size. Simply setting the url as you suggest implies that the image actually exists. And if it doesn't, you end up with a broken image icon. Toran's solution was correct, but he forgot to add "data:image/jpg;<data>".